# Como printo resultados de jquery em uma div?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Meu codigo js esta funcionando perfeitamente porem queria que me printase o resultado dentro de uma div na propria index.html a baixo do meu textarea e sem redirecionar para outra pagina, pois ele esta redirecionando pra pagina ip.php e mostrando os resultados lá.

```html
<html>

<head>
<title> testar ips </title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function enviar(){
    var bin = $("#bin_id").val();
    var linhaenviar = bin.split("\n");
    var index = 0;
    linhaenviar.forEach(function(value){

      setTimeout(

        function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'ip.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: "bin=" + value,
            success: function(resultado){
              document.write(resultado + "<br>");
          }
        })

      }, 10 * index);

    index = index + 3;

    })
  }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<center>
<textarea name="ip" id="ip_id" rows="10" cols="40">
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="testar ips" onclick="enviar();"></input>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, primeiro crie um `span` ou `div` em baixo do seu `textarea` com algum `id`.

```
<span id="msg"> </span>
```

Dentro da `function success` você pode usar a função `text()` selecionando o span:

```
success: function(){
   $("#msg").text("a mensagem que você quer");
}
```

Um pequeno exemplo para requisições ajax e php.

**JS**

```
  $("#cadastrar-produtos").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var dados = $(this).serialize();
    var url = "cadastrar-produto.php";

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: dados,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(json){
        if (json.status) {
          console.log("success");
          $("#cadastrar").each(function() {
            this.reset();
          });

          iziToast.success({
            title: 'Ok',
            message: json.message,
            icon: "zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"
          });

        } else {
          console.log("error");
          iziToast.error({
            title: 'Erro',
            message: json.message,
            icon: "zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"
          });

        }
      },
      error: function(json){
        iziToast.error({
          title: 'Erro',
          message: "Erro ao fazer requisição",
          icon: "zmdi zmdi-thumb-down"
        });
      }
    });

  });
```

Estou utilizando uma lib chamada iziToast, para exibir alertas do resultado.

**Php**

```
require_once 'class/Produto.php';
require_once 'class/ProdutoDAO.php';
require_once 'conecta.php';

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$preco = $_POST["preco"];
$quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"];
$validade = $_POST["validade"];
$descricao = $_POST["descricao"];

$produto = new Produto();
$dao = new ProdutoDAO($conexao);
$produto->setNome($nome);
$produto->setPreco($preco);
$produto->setQuantidade($quantidade);
$produto->setValidade($validade);
$produto->setDescricao($descricao);
try {
    if ($dao->inserir($produto)) {
        $json = array(
            "status" => "true",
            "message" => "Produto inserido com sucesso"
        );
    } else {
        $json = array(
            "status" => "false",
            "message" => "Erro ao inserir produto"
        );
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $json = array(
            "status" => "false",
            "message" => "Erro ao inserir produto: " . $e->getMessage()
        );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Eu achei muito interessante criar um array, como se fosse um objeto json, para guardar o status e uma mensagem. O status vai guardar se tudo aconteceu de maneira correta no meu back end, e uma mensagem como " Produto cadastrado com sucesso ". Na minha function success faço um `if(json.status)` se for true, é porque deu tudo certo, e mando um iziToast personalizado para mensagens de sucesso, caso contrario mando um iziToast personalizado para mensagens de erro.

Comment: Obrigado mais as mensagens a serem imprimidas são resultados do ip.php aonde tem requisições em curl e retornam o echo, oque eu realmente queria fazer e pegar do php echo $resultado; e printar na div da index como isso e feito  ?

Comment: coloque a variável resultado (que esta no parâmetro da function success) dentro da function text():     text(resultado);

Comment: editei a resposta colocando um pequeno exemplo de como printar resultados vindo do back end, no seu caso php

Comment: obrigado me ajudou muito :)

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode usar o comando HTML do jQuery no `success` da sua requisição AJAX:

```
$('#id_da_minha_div').html(meu_html)
```

Veja mais informações aqui: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Quem deu o -1, poderia explicar, por favor, o motivo aqui nos comentário ao menos?